# How do you remove HTTP links from the Run Task History in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, http, history, run-dialog

Here's a screenshot of the Run Task showing HTTP links.

[image]

And there are many instances of the Run Task showing up entries I haven't typed before, like ms-settings:network-vpn and so on. I wondered if this is related.

Anyway, how do I remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're read from the IE history. Clearing the history is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regedit` to edit your RUN history:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU
```

Comment: The HTTP links are still there.